# How to use Tensorflow GPU in C++ UWP application?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, uwp

I am trying to run tensorflow-gpu in my C ++ UWP application, but unfortunately it uses only the CPU.

My setup is the following: 
OS Platform: Windows 10 
TensorFlow version: 1.12.0 
CUDA/cuDNN version: I have two configuration (CUDA 10.0 / cuDNN 7.3 for CUDA 10.0) and (CUDA 9.0.17 and cuDNN 7.3 for CUDA 9.0) 
GPU model and memory: Nvidia GTX1060 
Environment: Visual Studio 2017 15.9

I installed tensorflow from various sources: 
 
https://github.com/Neargye/tensorflow/releases  
https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel 
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-1.12.0.zip 
and also downloaded tensorflow-gpu for python using anaconda (then tensorflow in python script uses GPU).

I copied all lib/dll files to output directory, set linker configuration (I added also all possible CUDA/cuDNN files and I tested combinations of these), but nothing is working.

I test if tensorflow sees GPU using the following code:

```
std::string getGPUDeviceName(TF_Session* session) 
{
    std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, decltype(&TF_DeleteStatus)> status(
        TF_NewStatus(), TF_DeleteStatus);

    std::unique_ptr<TF_DeviceList, decltype(&TF_DeleteDeviceList)> list(
        TF_SessionListDevices(session, status.get()), TF_DeleteDeviceList);
    auto device_list = list.get();

    auto num_devices = TF_DeviceListCount(device_list);
    for (auto i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
        auto device_name = TF_DeviceListName(device_list, i, status.get());
        auto device_type = TF_DeviceListType(device_list, i, status.get());

        if (device_type == DEVICE_GPU)
        {
            return device_name;
        }
    }
    // No GPU device found.
    return "";
}

std::string getGPUDeviceName() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, decltype(&TF_DeleteStatus)> status(TF_NewStatus(), TF_DeleteStatus);
    std::unique_ptr<TF_Graph, decltype(&TF_DeleteGraph)> graph(TF_NewGraph(),
                                                                TF_DeleteGraph);

    std::unique_ptr<TF_SessionOptions, decltype(&TF_DeleteSessionOptions)> opts (TF_NewSessionOptions(), 
                                                                                    TF_DeleteSessionOptions);
    std::unique_ptr < TF_Session, std::function<void(TF_Session*)>> sess(
        TF_NewSession(graph.get(), opts.get(), status.get()),
        [statusPtr = status.get()](auto sess) {TF_DeleteSession(sess, statusPtr); });

    return getGPUDeviceName(sess.get());
}
```

I don't have any idea, what I may do more in this topic.

Comment: According to Microsoft, CUDA is [not supported](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6f3fd386-e411-41f1-aa9d-4994ae078708/uwpccan-c-uwp-apps-use-cuda?forum=wpdevelop) in a UWP app.  Another similar comment is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2243)

Comment: It's bad news, but great thanks!